# How to call a method when user comes from outside of application but not when user is inside application

Tags: android

I want to call a method specially when user restart activity after pressing home button.

i tried this but its not working

```
@Override
 public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
     // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
    Log.d(TAG,"restart");
    blnIsApp=true;
 }
@Override
 public void onResume() {
     // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;        
    super.onResume();
    if(blnIsApp==false)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"external");

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG,"internal");
    }
    blnIsApp=false;
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean your onRestart in not getting called?

Comment: You can call your method inside `onResume()`. As when the `Home` key pressed, your application call `onPause()`. But when user comes back to app `onResume()` is called.

Comment: `onRestart()` is called when your app is no longer visible means android has killed to free the resources OR after.`onStop()` is called.

Comment: but the problem is when user navigates back to my activity from inside my app then i do not have to call the method.

Comment: Do you mean onWindowFocusChanged? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)